# How to fix the CS0234 - Assembly Reference Missing

Tags: visual-studio, nunit, specflow

I'm setting up SPECFLOW BDD project and when i build my project, I get below error:

In reference folder: I have "nunit.framework"

Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error   CS0234  The type or namespace name 'TestFixtureSetUpAttributeAttribute' does not exist in the namespace 'NUnit.Framework' (are you missing an assembly reference?)  SpecFlow Project2   C:\Users\source\repos\SpecFlow Project2\SpecFlow Project2\TestFeature.feature   3   N/A

Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error   CS0234  The type or namespace name 'TestFixtureSetUpAttribute' does not exist in the namespace 'NUnit.Framework' (are you missing an assembly reference?)   SpecFlow Project2   C:\Users\source\repos\SpecFlow Project2\SpecFlow Project2\TestFeature.feature   3   N/A

Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error   CS0234  The type or namespace name 'TestFixtureTearDownAttributeAttribute' does not exist in the namespace 'NUnit.Framework' (are you missing an assembly reference?)   SpecFlow Project2   C:\Users\source\repos\SpecFlow Project2\SpecFlow Project2\TestFeature.feature   12  N/A

Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error   CS0234  The type or namespace name 'TestFixtureTearDownAttribute' does not exist in the namespace 'NUnit.Framework' (are you missing an assembly reference?)    SpecFlow Project2   C:\Users\source\repos\SpecFlow Project2\SpecFlow Project2\TestFeature.feature   12  N/A

Comment: Which version of NUnit are you referencing?

Answer (score 1):

The SpecFlow Extension can't find the referenced SpecFlow version and falls back to the integrated generator (which is 1.9...).

Solution: use the MSBuild generation: https://specflow.org/2019/generating-code-behind-files-using-msbuild/